# role is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

I was working on discord.py when I ran into a problem, "role is a required argument that is missing"

I have tried to delete the ctx, but then I can't get the user name, or give a role.

```
@client.command()
async def GiveRole(ctx, role):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await client.give_roles(user, role)
    await client.say(“Role %s given to %s.” %(role,user))
```

It was supposed to give you the role specified in "role".

My whole code is:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import random
import discord
import operator
from discord.utils import get
import discord, datetime, time
from discord import Game
BOT_PREFIX = ("yaz ")
TOKEN = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
xp = {}

currentlink = "None"
currentmode = "None"
levels = {}
leader = ()
everyone = "off"
idname = {}
warns = {}
rewards = {}
xpstat = "on"
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
client.remove_command('help')


@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
   author = ctx.message.author
   embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.red())
   embed.set_author(name='HELP!')
   embed.add_field(name='yaz setlink <link WITHOUT https> <mode>', value='Sets the current server link!', inline=False)
   embed.add_field(name='yaz help', value='DM them help message :D', inline=False)
   embed.add_field(name='yaz link', value='Shows the current server link!', inline=False)
   await client.send_message(author,embed=embed)


@client.command()
async def level(ctx):
   global xp
   person = ctx.message.author.id
   lev = xp[person]["level"]
   xptotal = xp[person]["fullxp"]
   embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.green())
   embed.set_author(name='Level')
   embed.add_field(name='You are level %s.' %(lev),value='%s xp total.' %(xptotal),inline=False)
   await client.say(embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def addscore(ctx, score, mode, time, piclink):
   global lscore
   global xp
   global lmode
   lmode = mode
   lscore = score
   id = ctx.message.author.id
   rtime = time
   xp[id]["hightime"] = rtime
   xp[id]["highscore"] = lscore
   xp[id]["highmode"] = lmode
   xp[id]["highpic"] = piclink
   await client.say("Your score of %s is now on your profile!" %(lscore))

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def fan(ctx):
   fanyay = ctx.message.author.name
   await client.say("Thank you, %s! That was nice of you!" %(fanyay))


@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Yazmania")
async def rep(ctx, addremove, userid, amount=1):
   global xp
   if addremove == "add":
       xp[userid]["rep"] += amount
       await client.say("Given %s %s rep. (Hope they were a real person!)" %(userid,amount))
   if addremove == "remove":
       xp[userid]["rep"] -= amount
       await client.say("Removed %s rep from %s. (Hope they were a real person!)" %(amount,userid))



@client.command()
async def profile(ctx):
   global xp
   name = ctx.message.author.name
   id = ctx.message.author.id
   score = xp[id]["highscore"]
   mode = xp[id]["highmode"]
   pic = xp[id]["highpic"]
   lev = xp[id]["level"]
   money = xp[id]["coins"]
   rep = xp[id]["rep"]
   time = xp[id]["hightime"]
   xptotal = xp[id]["fullxp"]
   if name != "Yazmania":
       embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.green())
       embed.set_author(name='Profile:')
       embed.add_field(name='Hello, %s!' %(name), value='How may I help today, sir?', inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Highscore:', value='%s in %s. Looks like it took you %s to get that! Proof is %s.' %(score,mode,time,pic), inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Level:', value='You are level %s, with a total of %s xp!' %(lev, xptotal), inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Rep:', value='You have %s reputation, %s.' %(rep,name), inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Coins:', value='You have %s coin(s), %s.' %(money,name), inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Buy you a nice seafood dinner', value='and never call you again.', inline=False)
       await client.say(embed=embed)
   else:
       embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.red())
       embed.set_author(name='God:')
       embed.add_field(name='Hello, YAZMANIA, THE OWNER!!!!!!', value='I BOW DOWN TO YOU YAZ :place_of_worship:', inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Highscore:', value='%s in %s. Looks like it took you %s to get that! Proof is %s. But you are YAZMANIA, so it does not really matter!' %(score,mode,time,pic), inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Level:', value='You are level ∞, with a total of ∞ xp! YAZMANIA :smile:', inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Rep:', value='You have ∞ reputation YAZMANIA because you are too cool to have less than ∞.', inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='Coins:', value='You have %s coins, but you can just use `yaz give <id> <coins>`.' %(money), inline=False)
       embed.add_field(name='THANK YOU YAZMANIA', value='Subscribe to Yazmania!', inline=False)
       await client.say(embed=embed)


@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Yazmania")
async def clear(ctx, amount=10):
   channel = ctx.message.channel
   messages = []
   async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount)):
       messages.append(message)
   await client.delete_messages(messages)
   author = ctx.message.author
   await client.send_message(author,"Rip %s messages... you will be missed :sob:" %(amount))

@client.command()
async def game(game):
   await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="%s" %(game)))
   await client.say("I am now playing %s." %(game))


@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
   global xp
   coins = round(random.random() + 1 * 5)
   name = ctx.message.author.name
   id = ctx.message.author.id
   xp[id]["coins"] += coins
   await client.say("%s, you just collected your daily bonus of %s coins!" %(name,coins))


@client.command()
async def setlink(link, mode):
   global currentlink
   global currentmode
   global xp
   currentlink = "https://" + link
   currentmode = mode
   await client.send_message(destination=client.get_channel("529144661810479104"), content='The link for a %s game is %s' %(currentmode,currentlink))
   await client.say("The Current Server link has been set to %s with mode %s." %(currentlink,currentmode))

@client.command()
async def link():
   global currentlink
   global currentmode
   await client.say("Want to join a(n) %s game? Here's the link: %s" %(currentmode,currentlink))  

@client.command()
async def promotelink():
   global currentlink
   global currentmode
   await client.send_message(destination=client.get_channel("529138809246580747"), content='Join a %s game! %s' %(currentmode,currentlink))
   await client.say("Promotion complete.")


@client.command()
async def removelink():
   global currentlink
   global currentmode
   currentlink = "`error`"
   currentmode = "`error`"
   await client.say("Link deleted.") 

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   global xpstat
   global idname
   global xp
   global leader
   global levels
   id = message.author.id
   msgname = message.author.name
   idname[id] = message.author.name
   if id != client.user.id and id in xp and xpstat != "off":
       xp[id]["xp"] = xp[id]["xp"] + 1
       xp[id]["fullxp"] = xp[id]["fullxp"] + 1
       print("%s by %s" %(message,id))
       if xp[id]["xp"] > xp[id]["wait"]:
           xp[id]["xp"] = 0
           xp[id]["wait"] *= 1.5
           xp[id]["level"] += 1
           levels[id] += 1
           await client.send_message(message.channel, "Level up %s! You are now level %s!" %(msgname,xp[id]["level"]))
           xp[id]["rep"] += 5
           print("%s just leveled up to level %s!" %(id, xp[id]["level"]))
   else:
       xp[id] = {"coins": 25,"xp": 0, "level": 1, "wait": 25, "fullxp": 0, "highscore": 0, "highmode": "please set a mode.", "highpic": "https://postimages.org", "rep": 100, "hightime": "0:00"}
       levels[id] = 0
   await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="Yazmania is NEAT!"))
   print("YazBot is ready to go!")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated. This error has not happened before.

Comment: Can you post from where GiveRole method is being called?

Comment: i just edited the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the context in the `async` version of discord.py

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def GiveRole(ctx, role:discord.Role):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await client.add_roles(ctx.message.author,role)
    await client.say(f"Role {role.name} give to {ctx.message.author.display_name}")
```

To be able to use the attribute of the role, you have to first convert it into a role object by doing `role:discord.Role`. Also by not doing `pass_context=True` you are unable to use the attributes of the context meaning that you won't be able to get attribute values such as the username of the person that triggered the command, also it should be `add_roles()` and lastly please check out the official documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)